# usar propiedad de una clase como valor predeterminado

Tags: php, clase, refactoring

tengo una clase
y en el constructor determino el valor de una propiedad de la clase;
por que no puedo utilizar esta propiedad de la clase como un valor predeterminado en un método?

o será que no estoy utilizando la propiedad o tipo de propiedad adecuada?

```
class FooClass
{
    public string $defenv = '';
    public function __construct($theme = 'default')
    {
        //En el constructor determino el tipo de interface usada
        $this->defenv = $this->IsCommandLineInterface() ? 'cli' : 'web';
    }
    private function IsCommandLineInterface()
    {
        return (php_sapi_name() === 'cli');
    }
    public function foo($env = $this->defenv){
        echo $env;
    }
}
```

Error

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in

me veo en la necesidad de hacer estos cambios para que funcione (sigue estando dentro de la clase):

```
public function foo($env = ''){
    if ($env == '') {
        $env = $this->defenv;
    }
    echo $env;
}
```

Nota:
previamente he instanciado la clase y llamo de la siguiente forma:

```
$example = new FooClass();
$example->foo()
```

Comment: Supongo que es porque al momento de definir el método todavía no está instanciada la clase, por lo que `$this` es nulo (o indefinido). Podrías usar el [operador de fusión _null_](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op): `echo $env ?? $this->defenv;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El caso particular que deseas resolver puede lograrse. Pero, generando la constante que se va a usar mediante el uso del método [define()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.define) que admite el uso de funciones que retornen algún valor como valores a asignar.
La solución podría plantearse así:

```
<?php
\**
 * @filename: FooClass.php
 */
define('ENTORNO', IdentificarEntorno() ); 

class FooClass
{
    public string $defenv = '';
    public function __construct($theme = 'default')
    {
        //En principio no se necesitaría asignar la propiedad a no ser
        //que se espere que la usen clases derivadas de ella.
        // la asigno para mantenerla.
        // Podría haberse asignado directamente en la declaración y
        //es redundante con la constante declarada.
        $this->defenv = ENTORNO;
    }
    
    public function foo($env = ENTORNO){
        echo $env;
    }
}

function IdentificarEntorno()
{
    return (php_sapi_name() === 'cli') ? 'cli' : 'web';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En la documentación de `PHP` en la sección [Valores de argumentos predeterminados](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) dice:

> El valor predeterminado debe ser una expresión constante, no (por ejemplo) una variable, un miembro de una clase o una llamada a una función.

Una solución (*como [comento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/431068/usar-propiedad-de-una-clase-como-valor-predeterminado#comment769613_431068) @Triby*) es usar el [operador de fusión de null](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

#### Ejemplo:

```
public function foo($env = null){
    echo $env ?? $this->defenv;
}
```